# Add Federation(SSO) protocol plugin to my website for Single Sign On

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, saml, openam, federation

I have an OpenAM Identity management and a website that needs its credentials for loggin in. I want to federate my website with Google. My web site doesn't support any Federation protocol. How can I do this? Is there any module or plugin for each protocol to deploy in my site? should I change my source code ?

Answer (score 0):

You should potentially set up federation between Google and OpenAM, and then use a policy agent or OpenIG to protect your application.

Even though both the agents and OpenIG tries to make the integration as transparent as possible, it may be necessary to modify the application (for example to ensure that the app reads the user name out of an HTTP request header/cookie/etc, and possibly some other modifications to interact with the application's authorization framework).

Comment: Is there any sample code for OpenIG? as I said, my website doesn't support any federation protocol

Comment: OpenIG is/includes a lightweight SAMLv2 SP